# Unregister sidebar from Child-Theme

Tags: sidebar, child-theme

I like to use a child-theme.

The parent functions.php

```
function starkers_widgets_init() {
// Area 1, located at the top of the sidebar.
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area', 'starkers' ),
    'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'starkers' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li>',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

// Area 2 ...
```

My child-theme functions.php

```
function xtreme_unregister_sidebar() {
    unregister_sidebar('primary-widget-area');
    }
    add_action( 'childtheme_sidebars', 'xtreme_unregister_sidebar' );
```

But doesn´t work for.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code bellow, I think that should work.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_default_sidebars', 11 );
function remove_default_sidebars(){
    remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'starkers_widgets_init' );
}
```

Comment: I just edit the quotes  // Remove all widgets from Starkers-Theme
`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_default_sidebars', 11 );
function remove_default_sidebars(){
remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'starkers_widgets_init' );
}`

Answer (score 2):

The Title of this post is for unregistering widgets not really sidebars, though I am glad the user got what they were looking for. For those searching for how to unregister widgets using a child-theme where the widget was registered in the parent theme, you can do that with this:

Assuming the Parent Theme's Widget is registered at the widgets_init hook, all you need to do is wrap your unregister_widget() call inside of a function, hook that function into widgets_init, and give your hook a higher priority number than the Parent Theme's widgets_init-hooked function.

Assuming the Parent Theme hooks into widgets_init without giving a priority number, the function will default to 10. So, just give your hook call a priority of 11 or greater.

so something like this:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_theme_widgets', 11 );

function remove_theme_widgets() {
    unregister_widget('parent_theme_widget_class');
}
```

[`Source`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget#Example)

Comment: A note for future readers that will not understand why @leogopal answered referring to widgets: in the meanwhile I fixed the title and tags of the original question that previously was "Unregister widget from Child-Theme". Apparently from _ogni_ question (and according to the accepted answer) he/her was referring to sidebars not single widgets, despite the previously given title. _legopal_ answer is still a good answer (more descriptive than the approved one, BTW): give it a look if you are trying to remove a sidebar but you just need to remove a widget :)